# What's the error mean for `$in` in Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
for element in self.table1.find({'ji': {'$ne': ""}}):
    gongLiNian = int(element['gongLiNian'])
    gongLiNianScope = [str(gongLiNian-1), str(gongLiNian), str(gongLiNian+1)]
    res = self.table2.find_one({'guanZhi' : element['guanZhi'],
                             'gongLiNian' : {'$in', gongLiNianScope},
                                'name'    :  element['name']})
```

For this code, here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop\study\History\oneJi.py", line 172, in <module>
    oneJi.run()
  File "C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop\study\History\oneJi.py", line 158, in run
    res1 = self.step1()
  File "C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop\study\History\oneJi.py", line 44, in step1
    'gongLiNian' : {'$in', gongLiNianScope},
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

But i can't find any clue from the error.Could you give me some advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comma here:

```
{'$in', gongLiNianScope}
```

that is a syntax to initialize a set and you can put only *hashable* data types into a set.

Instead, you meant to have a dictionary:

```
{'$in': gongLiNianScope}
```